# Creation copy of file in javascript, size issue

Tags: file, object, copy

First of all I know that File object is immutable. I want to have a copy of file with new name. I use react-dropzone to drag and drop files and whenever I find the duplicate file (name) I would like to add the (1) to file file name. For example:
Dog.docx -> found next Dog.docx -> Dog(1).docx;

What I have already done is:

let newName = lastFile.name + "(" + 1 + ")";

```
newFile = new File(XXX, newName, {
                        preview: lastFile.preview,
                        lastModified: lastFile.lastModified,
                        lastModifiedDate: lastFile.lastModifiedDate,
                        webkitRelativePath: lastFile.webkitRelativePath,
                        type: lastFile.type
                    });
```

The XXX is because I do know know how to put the same size as lastFile has.

So basically: I want a copy of file with changed name.

Thanks a lot for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
newFile = new File([lastFile], newName, {
                        preview: lastFile.preview,
                        lastModified: lastFile.lastModified,
                        lastModifiedDate: lastFile.lastModifiedDate,
                        webkitRelativePath: lastFile.webkitRelativePath,
                        type: lastFile.type
                    });
```